# Find and Replace VB Macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using a Find and Replace script/macro in MS Word. For the two lines below, how would I adjust this to be case sensitive? Right now it will replace us, bus, ect..

Const strFind As String = "US"
 Const strRepl As String = "USA"

```
Sub BatchProcess()
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim oDoc As Document
Dim fDialog As FileDialog
Dim oStory As Range
Dim oRng As Range
Const strFind As String = "2017"
Const strRepl As String = "2018"
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fDialog
    .Title = "Select folder and click OK"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
    If .Show <> -1 Then
        MsgBox "Cancelled By User", , _
               "List Folder Contents"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    strPath = fDialog.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
End With
strFileName = Dir$(strPath & "*.docx")
While Len(strFileName) <> 0
    WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros 1
    Set oDoc = Documents.Open(strPath & strFileName)
    For Each oStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        Set oRng = oStory
        With oRng.Find
            Do While .Execute(FindText:=strFind)
                oRng.Text = strRepl
                oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            Loop
        End With
        If oStory.StoryType <> wdMainTextStory Then
            While Not (oStory.NextStoryRange Is Nothing)
                Set oStory = oStory.NextStoryRange
                Set oRng = oStory
                With oRng.Find
                    Do While .Execute(FindText:=strFind)
                        oRng.Text = strRepl
                        oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                    Loop
                End With
            Wend
        End If
    Next oStory
    oDoc.SaveAs FileName:=strPath & strFileName
    oDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    strFileName = Dir$()
    WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros 0
  Wend
  Set oDoc = Nothing
  Set oStory = Nothing
  Set oRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

In response to the post below. I have added the entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Find and Replace method has a boolean MatchCase property. Set it to True.

Example: In your DoWhile code. Do While .Execute(FindText:=strFind, MatchCase:=True)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is fairly new to me. Exactly where/how would I add it to the code above.

Comment: @cjenkins08 In your DoWhile code. Do While .Execute(FindText:=strFind, MatchCase:=True)

Answer (score 0):

Simply matching the case is insufficient if what you're searching for as a whole word might also exist within a larger string. Try:

```
Sub BatchProcess()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strFileName As String, strPath As String
Dim oDoc As Document, oStory As Range
Dim fDialog As FileDialog
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fDialog
  .Title = "Select folder and click OK"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
  .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
  If .Show <> -1 Then
    MsgBox "Cancelled By User", , "List Folder Contents"
    Exit Sub
  End If
  strPath = fDialog.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
End With
strFileName = Dir$(strPath & "*.docx")
WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros 1
While Len(strFileName) <> 0
  Set oDoc = Documents.Open(strPath & strFileName)
  With oDoc
  For Each oStory In .StoryRanges
    While Not (oStory Is Nothing)
      oStory.Find.Execute FindText:="<US>", Replacewith:="USA", Forward:=True, _
        Wrap:=wdFindContinue, MatchWildcards:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Set oStory = oStory.NextStoryRange
      Wend
    Next oStory
    .SaveAs FileName:=strPath & strFileName
    .Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
  End With
  strFileName = Dir$()
Wend
WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros 0
Set oDoc = Nothing:  Set oStory = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note that I've used wildcards, combined with  as the Find expression. That guarantees only whole upper-case words will be matched. you could achieve the same with:

```
      oStory.Find.Execute FindText:="US", Replacewith:="USA", Forward:=True, _
        Wrap:=wdFindContinue, MatchWholeWord:=True, MatchCase:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Note, too, the overall simplification of your code.